# Как выгружать файлы из сервера в Unity

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server, unity3d

Делаю таблицу лидеров. Загружаю данные пользователя при регистрации через WWWForm и WWW. Весь текст хранится в SQL, а фото хранится как бинарный файл в папке сервера. Но никак не могу найти как все это выгрузить обратно в Unity? Чем пользоваться в php коде на выгрузку и в самом Unity скрипте? Спасибо.

Comment: [Unity Docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/WWWForm.html) Смотри второй скрипт, загрузка с SQL сервера

Answer (score 0):

php код:

```
<?PHP
$name = $_POST['name'];
if (file_exists("Avatars/".$name)) {
$file = fopen("Avatars/".$name,"r");
$data = fread($file, 2000000);
fclose($file);
echo $data;
}
?>
```

Unity

```
void GetAva(string name)
{
    WWWForm form = new WWWForm();
    form.AddField("name", name);
    WWW www = new WWW(getavaURL, form);
    StartCoroutine(GetBinAva(www));
}
IEnumerator GetBinAva(WWW www)
{
    yield return www;
    binaryAva = www.bytes;
    www.Dispose();
    Draw();
}
void Draw()
{
    Texture2D texture = new Texture2D(2, 2);
    texture.LoadImage(binaryAva);
    Test.texture = texture;
}
```

Здесь binaryAva - byte[], хранящая текстуру в байтовом виде.